# Use Generic ILogger Instance with Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, ilogger, loggerfactory

I have the following Code.

```
public class TypeA : InterfaceA
{
    private ILogger _logger;
    public TypeA(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    ...
    var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
    ILogger<TypeA> typeALogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TypeA>();
    var typeAObj = new TypeA(typeALogger);
    ...
}
```

I want to use autofac to create the instance of TypeA like so:

```
// Autofac is configured ...

using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
var typeAObj = scope.Resolve<InterfaceA>();
```

How can I do this, but using the `ILogger<TypeA>` Logger from the existing `LoggerFactory`, as argument for the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse the existing Microsoft logging infrastructure you can reuse the build-in DI setup via `AutofacRegistration.Populate` from `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` (a bit of [docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html#quick-start)):

```cs
public class TypeA : InterfaceA
{
    private ILogger _logger;
    public TypeA(ILogger<TypeA> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

And registration:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// setup logging infrastructure via build-in DI
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => {}); 

// pass the setup to the Autofac
builder.Populate(services);
        
builder.RegisterType<TypeA>().As<InterfaceA>();
  
// use it      
var container = builder.Build();
using var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
var typeAObj = scope.Resolve<InterfaceA>();
```

Comment: I am not completely sure, if this is what I had in mind. I need to find some time for checking it and will definitively come back and let you know. Anyway, thanks in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could use autofac's `RegisterGeneric`.

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>))
        .As(typeof(ILogger<>));
```

You'll need an instance of `ILogger`, so use `ILoggerFactory` to create it:

```
    builder.Register<ILoggerFactory>(context =>
        LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            builder.AddConsole()
        )
    ).SingleInstance();
```